# Jclouds logging with SLF4j + log4j instead of SLF4J + logback

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback, jclouds

I'm not a Java expert, but I'm working on a project which already uses SLF4J + log4j. I'm adding Jclouds as a dependency and I saw that it used SLF4J + logback. Is it possibile to use SLF4J + log4j event for Jclouds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLF4J is supported, that is clear. And I just found the following (apache-written) library:

[JClouds-log4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jclouds.driver/jclouds-log4j)

which indicates that log4j is natively supported as well. **This means that you will have no problem using slf4j with log4j**, altough it is worth mention, that slf4j with logback seems to be the more "modern" approach. Of course if you have some specific reason (dealing with a legacy app for example) to stick to log4j, then you should go with that one.

Answer (score 1):

jclouds supports both Log4j and SLF4j. You can use the, directly by including the `Log4JLoggingModule` or `SLF4JLoggingModule` when creating the context. It is as simple as declaring the module and having the driver dependency in your pom.xml.

If you want to use Log4j over the SLF4j interface you will also need to include the [log4j-slf4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) bridge dependency.

You will find a couple detailed examples on how to configure it in the [jclouds Logging documentation page](http://jclouds.apache.org/reference/logging/).